# Pandas columns by given value in last row

Tags: pandas

Below my dataframe "df" made of 34 columns (pairs of stocks) and 530 rows (their respective cumulative returns). 'Date' is the index

[image]

Now, my target is to consider last row (Date=3 Febraury 2021). I want to plot ONLY those columns (pair stocks) that have a positive return on last Date.

I started with:

```
n=list()
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df.iloc[-1,i] >0:
        n.append(i)
```

Output: [3, 11, 12, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30]

Now, final step is to create a subset dataframe of 'df' containing only columns belonging to those numbers in this list. This is where I have problems. Have you any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
n = []
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if df.iloc[-1,i] > 0:
        n.append(col)
        
df[n]
```

Here you are ;)

Comment: kaRaOkEy it works! 

It's clear I have to better understand 'enumerate' ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: I'd appreciate if you accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

sample df:

```
             a    b      c
date            
2017-04-01  0.5   -0.7  -0.6
2017-04-02  1.0   1.0    1.3
```

---

```
df1.loc[df1.index.astype(str) == '2017-04-02', df1.ge(1.2).any()]
```

---

```
            c
date    
2017-04-02  1.3
```

the logic will be same for your case also.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want columns with IDs `[3, 11, 12, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30]`, am I right?
You should use `DataFrame.iloc`:

```py
column_ids = [3, 11, 12, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30]
df_subset = df.iloc[:, column_ids].copy()
```

The ":" on the left side of `df.iloc` means "all rows". I suggest using `copy` method in case you want to perform additional operations on `df_subset` without the risk to affect the original `df`, or raising Warnings.

If instead of a list of column IDs, you have a list of column names, you should just replace `.iloc` with `.loc`.